Why does the add instruction in assembly seemingly make an implicit sizeof() conversion?
Consider the following x86 ASM instructions:
mov     eax, [ebp+StrPointer]
add     eax, 1
mov     [ebp+StrPointer], eax 

Here, [ebp+StrPointer] is a pointer to some heap allocated string. Apparently, in tandem these instructions would update the pointer to point to the next character in the string.
What I don't understand, is why in the second instruction, add eax, 1, we don't instead add 4. I can understand that what is happening is 1 byte is added to the eax register, and since memory is byte addressed, 1 byte is the next memory address. But how/why is 1 interpreted as "1 byte" and not just 1?
For example, if the [ebp+StrPointer] had a value of 0xFFF0, then I would think that add eax, 1 would result in a value of 0xFFF1, but instead the aforementioned behavior suggests it would instead be 0xFFF4. Why?
In C, I can understand the explanation that the compiler turns something like
int a = 1;
int *ptr = &a;
ptr = ptr + 1;

into
ptr = ptr + sizeof(int)*1

But at the assembly level there is no sizeof call. So whats going on?

Where does 4 come from? If that's from sizeof(int) on your system, what's the relationship between that and "the next character in the string"?

sizeof is a compile time feature

You are correct that C automatically scales the integer in pointer arithmetic (i.e. pointer + integer  => pointer) by the element size.  However, the assembly code you're showing above does not correspond to the pointer arithmetic you're showing in C below, so not a valid comparison

As others say, sizeof is a built in rather than a function call.  It does not require ()'s.  What needs the () is the cast syntax type expression (int).  We can do sizeof i without (), just like we can do return i; without ().  Of course we can always add more () to return for return(i); making it look like a function call, or sizeof(i), however we cannot add extra () to the sizeof cast: so sizeof((int)) is an error.  I usually write it as sizeof (int) where that extra space between emphasizes the cast syntax type expression part.

sizeof isn't a function call so obviously there won't be any call. It's an operator because you can use sizeof ptr without any parentheses

Ok, so sizeof is a built in, similar to return. Why is there no equivalent assembly instruction, like there is retn? When running add eax, 1 does the assembler implicitly look at the data type in eax to figure out what the proper "unit" is? If [ebp+StrPointer] instead pointed to an array of ints rather than chars, would add eax, 1 increment eax by sizeof(int)? Is this true in general for different data types, and different assembly instructions?

Alternatively, if [epb+StrPointer] did point to an array of ints (assuming they are 4 bytes) would the assembly instead look like add eax, 4?

"would add eax, 1 increment eax by sizeof(int)" — no, that's what "high level" languages do, but not assemblers.  However, masm has a sizeof operator that can vary based on declarations.  Many other assemblers (e.g. for other processors) don't have anything like that. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-sizeof?view=msvc-170

"When running add eax, 1 does the assembler implicitly look at the data type in eax to figure out what the proper "unit" is?" — no, it doesn't know about data types in registers; that information is only in the head of the programmer.  It looks at add eax, 1 and assembles that literally into add eax, 1, trusting the text and the program/programmer that wrote it.

"point to an array of ints (assuming they are 4 bytes) would the assembly instead look like add eax, 4" — yes, if that add is advancing a pointer to the next element.  But no, if that add is adding to an integer element in the array, which is what your code example is doing.

Strings in C are char (not int arrays). The compiler knows the size of the object referenced by the pointer and adjust the address in generated code accordingly.
Bear in mind that ++ptr will move the reference held in ptr to the next object, not next byte.
void foo(char *s)
{
    while(*s) 
    {
        *s++ = 'a';
    }
}

foo:                                    # @foo
        cmp     byte ptr [rdi], 0
        je      .LBB0_3
        inc     rdi
.LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     byte ptr [rdi - 1], 97
        cmp     byte ptr [rdi], 0
        lea     rdi, [rdi + 1]
        jne     .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:
        ret

void bar(int *i)
{
    while(*i) 
    {
        *i++ = 9999;
    }
}

bar:                                    # @bar
        cmp     dword ptr [rdi], 0
        je      .LBB1_3
        add     rdi, 4
.LBB1_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     dword ptr [rdi - 4], 9999
        cmp     dword ptr [rdi], 0
        lea     rdi, [rdi + 4]
        jne     .LBB1_2
.LBB1_3:
        ret



You're confused.  This code
mov     eax, [ebp+StrPointer]
add     eax, 1
mov     [ebp+StrPointer], eax 

is equivalent to
int a = *ptr;
a = a + 1
*ptr = a;

or more concisely
++*ptr;

That is, you're not incrementing or changing the pointer in any way (no pointer arithmetic), you are incrementing the value you fetched from the pointer, and then storing it back via the (same) pointer.
Incrementing the pointer would likely be something more like
add    ebp, 4


I disagree with your interpretation of the OP assembly code. I think it should be char *StrPointer; ... ++StrPointer;.

@prl is correct, this is assembly that was dissasembled via IDA, and the source code did indeed increment the pointer itself, not the value.

In the asm code StrPointer must be a constant.  It might well be the address offset of a local variable in the stack frame, but it is a constant.  In any case, what this code is doing is incrementing the value pointed at by ebp+StrPointer.  Whether that value is an int or a char * is unclear.

"Here, [ebp+StrPointer] is a pointer to some heap allocated string" it is a char *
